# SQL replace value wildcard

Tags: mysql, sql, replace

I've tried searching stackoverflow for an answer but couldn't find any (M*ight be my mistake by not understanding?)*.

Anyway, I'm looking for a SQL Query that replaces **X** with **Y**.
(I'm using MySQL as DMBS)

The problem is that **X** is not **static**.
X variates from `[hello=world], [hello=planet], [hello=goodbye]`.

Is there anyway I can wildcard the parts after =?

The reason why I'm asking this is because I want to mass replace it.

`UPDATE messages
set hello = replace(hello,'?','[replacement]')`

Thank you!

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: Woops, I'm using MySQL, thanks!

Comment: `updat messages set hello = [replacement] where hello like '[hello%'`

Comment: @RabNawaz, thank you for your input. Will `'hello%'` select the `[hello=world]`, `[hello=planet]` etc?

Comment: `%` is used for wildcard search. if you are sure that all of your fields start with "[hello". then yes "[hello% will work. if "hello" is in the middle the string then  you can use "%hello%".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`update messages set hello = [replacement] where hello like '[hello%'`

`%` is used for wildcard comparison in text. if you are sure that all of your fields start with "[hello". then "[hello% will work in your case. if "hello" is in the middle the text and you are not sure about the start of the text. then you can use "%hello%".

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much! (Also one thing, don't forget to edit `updat` to `update`*

Comment: One more question, what if I want to make sure I don't replace other stuff. I only want to replace the % within the []. Would I do  %[hello=%]% ?

Comment: should be using `LIKE '[CK]ars[eo]n' searches for Carsen, Karsen, Carson, and Karson (Carson).` see this page for detail. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187489(v=sql.105).aspx